# Avoiding if..else ladder while adding to an Array, in an Object

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to avoid the `if..else` condition in the following code and do this in a single line?

```
var myObject = {},
    data = ["Chennai", "Thoothukkudi", "Madurai",
            "Coimbatore", "Trichy", "Salem", "Tirunelveli",
            "Erode", "Vellore", "Tiruppur"];

data.forEach(function(currentCity) {
    if (currentCity[0] in myObject) {
        myObject[currentCity[0]].push(currentCity);
    } else {
        myObject[currentCity[0]] = [currentCity];
    }
});

console.log(myObject);
```

**Output**

```
{ C: [ 'Chennai', 'Coimbatore' ],
  T: [ 'Thoothukkudi', 'Trichy', 'Tirunelveli', 'Tiruppur' ],
  M: [ 'Madurai' ],
  S: [ 'Salem' ],
  E: [ 'Erode' ],
  V: [ 'Vellore' ] }
```

The problem is, I have to do this `if..else` check in many places in my code. If I do that in 8 places, it adds up to 40 lines. So, I am looking for a way to write that in a single line.

In Python, there is something called `defaultdict` and a normal dict also can be used with `setdefault` function. Is there any elegant and short (less number of lines) way to do this?

Comment: shouldn't be asked @ [code-review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) ?

Comment: Write a reusable named function.

Comment: You can use Ternary Operator @thefourtheye

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
myObject[currentCity[0]] = myObject[currentCity[0]] || [];
myObject[currentCity[0]].push(currentCity);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add those lines to a separate function, and then you only have to call it once in each instance:

```
function wrangleCity(currentCity, myObject) {
  if (currentCity[0] in myObject) {
    myObject[currentCity[0]].push(currentCity);
  } else {
    myObject[currentCity[0]] = [currentCity];
  }
}

data.forEach(function (currentCity) {
  wrangleCity(currentCity, myObject);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/79Cn6/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
    var myObject = {},
        data = ["Chennai", "Thoothukkudi", "Madurai",
                "Coimbatore", "Trichy", "Salem", "Tirunelveli",
                "Erode", "Vellore", "Tiruppur"],

    data.map(v => {

         myObject.hasOwnProperty(v[0]) 
         ? myObject[v[0]].push(v) 
         : myObject[v[0]] = [v] 
    });

console.log("final result",myObject)
```

compare to `Array.Prototype.forEach`? `Array.Prototype.map`  utilizes return values and actually returns a new Array of the same size.